# Strange: Google indexing onload generated content?

Tags: javascript, google-index

I've noticed in Google's results page that my website's listing details (i.e. bellow the link) displays content that is only generated during the page onload function.

This surprised me as I thought Google does not index JavaScript generated content. Later I came across [this post](http://rogeralsing.com/2013/08/11/angularjs-and-seo-part-2/) showing a way to create `<title>` and meta description tags using AngularJS directives (which are only interpreted during onload)! So does this actually work? I would also appreciate some reference if it does and Google indeed indexes the page after running its onload.

Answer (score 2):

Google has been known to [crawl and handle some JavaScript for some time now](https://www.google.com/search?q=matt%20cutts%20google%20javacsript) so this isn't really much of a surprise. Especially when you consider that [Google is the author of Angularjs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AngularJS). So basically nothing unusual here.